# Creating NuGet Package with Package References

Tags: .net, nuget

I am creating a package that itself has package references:

[image]

Also here [Bootstrap4NHibernate](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bootstrap4NHibernate/)

As you can see I have added the package references to the package OK. However, when I add this package to a project it doesn't add references to the downstream package dlls (FluentNHib, MPM.PDAG etc).  I'm guessing I need to configure the package specifically to do this but I'm not sure how?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by adding the references without putting them in a group.  The NuGet Package Explorer doesn't allow you to do this so I exported the package to a nuspec file, took the packages out of the group tag, reloaded the nuspec file and now I'm sorted.

This clearly has something to do with groups/framework versions, so perhaps my fix isn't the best fix but it works in my use case.